# How to use the C++ functions of OpenCV from Python?

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I'm using the Python bindings of OpenCV and it's really great. However, there are functions in the C++ version that are missing from the Python bindings, BackgroundSubstractorMOG2, and a lots of feature detection algorithms for example. What would be the easiest way to call them from Python?

Comment: I feel your pain. Python is definitely a 2nd class citizen in opencv. I haven't used BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 but I've used various feature detection parts. Which ones are you wanting to use? I hope someone answers this as it would help me as well to get access to FREAK feature detection/description.

Comment: boost has a reportedly nice c++/python binding. i haven't used it. but worth looking up.

Comment: I'd use FREAK, FAST, ORB...etc if I could.

Comment: I've googled around and I know of boost and the likes, but I don't know which is the most convenient solution to use.

Comment: @b_m FAST, ORB, SURF, SIFT, and [maybe even BRISK](https://github.com/kobejohn/python_brisk_demo) already work in python.

Comment: @kobejohn you're right, thanks, I didn't see it in the documentation but now I found an example.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps people looking for a fast and easy way.

Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/Algomorph/pyboostcvconverter) with the open C++ code I wrote for exposing code using OpenCV's Mat class with as little pain as possible. It was originally inspired by [Yati Sagade's example](https://github.com/yati-sagade/blog-content/blob/master/content/numpy-boost-python-opencv.rst).

[Update] This code now works for **OpenCV 2.X** and **OpenCV 3.X**. CMake and <s>experimental</s> support for Python 3.X are now also available.

I also found that a few months after my original utility was written, Sudeep Pillai also wrote a [similar thing](https://github.com/spillai/numpy-opencv-converter) for C++/CMake. There seems to be OpenCV 2 and OpenCV 3 support as well. May be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/). It Python base and it a warping OpenCV. Maybe you can found something there.