# using python for opencv

Tags: python, opencv

There are many functions in OpenCV 2.4 not available using Python. 
Please advice me how to convert the C++ functions so that I can use in Python 2.7.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same question a few month ago. Haven't found the right solution since. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942656/how-to-use-the-c-functions-of-opencv-from-python

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Python Boost. This might help you to bind C++ functions you need to python.